# UIScrollView scroll vertically by touch and horizontally programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

I have looked on stackoverflow, but unable to find an answer that exactly answers my question. If I missed something, please point me to the correct question.

Here is my scenario --

I originally had a case where my vertical window size was set, so it was easy for me to restrict scrolling completely simply by doing this --

```
CGRect scrollContainer = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440);
self.baseView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollContainer];
self.baseView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6400, 440);
self.baseView.bounces = NO;
self.baseView.pagingEnabled = NO;
self.baseView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Based on the movement of the phone, I was then able to scroll programmatically --

```
CGPoint scrollOffset = CGPointMake(x*20, 0);
[self.baseView setContentOffset:scrollOffset];
```

In my new requirement, the vertical content increases drastically so I would have the contentSize like so

```
self.baseView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6400, 4400);
```

I still want to scroll horizontally programmatically, but give the user the ability to scroll ONLY vertically by touch. So, I'm assuming I would have to say scrollEnabled = YES. But this lets the user scroll in both directions.

Do I have to capture touch events and override them ? How would I recognize if it was a horizontal scroll or a vertical scroll? What happens if its a diagonal scroll action?

I'm a bit clueless at this point, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably be able to do this by nesting two `UIScrollViews`.

The inner scroll view would have `contentSize` of the actual content and its actual dimensions would be screen width and the same height as `contentSize`
with scrolling disabled.

The outer scroll view would have it's `contentSize` be the same as the outer scroll view's dimensions and it's actual dimensions would be the screen dimensions with scrolling enabled.

This way the user can scroll up and down on the outer view while you control the horizontal offset programmatically with the inner view.

It's a little complex but at least you don't have to subclass. :D

(Also will only work with iOS 3.0+) but that doesn't seem to be a problem)

[See "Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS" section on "Nesting Scroll Views"]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I wanted to scroll vertically, one of the scroll views would have to have their content size larger than the screen size , correct? Would that be the innner scroll view or the outer ?

Comment: I will try this out this evening and provide feedback. Appreciate the answer. innerscrollview = entire content size with scrolling disabled. outerscrollview.width = screen width .. add innnerscrollview to outerscrollview and enable screen interaction for outerscrollview. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Kal The inner scrollView also has only screen width width, but its contentSize is the complete contentSize. Its height is contentSize.height. Thus, the outer, touch-enabled scrollView scrolls *the entire inner scrollView* (it has contentSize = innerScrollView.size), and you can control the inner scrollView's horizontal contentOffset from your code, because the user has no chance to change that.

Comment: This worked. I didnt realize how easy this was until I tried it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to recognize a series of touch events as a vertical or horizontal swipe.

```
// ensure that automatic scrolling is not enabled
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                           initWithTarget:self 
                                           action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];
```

In your `handleGesture:` method, you can now adjust the `scrollOffset` appropriately. Read up on [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I also think two scrollViews is the answer here. If you don't want to nest them, link their data in the controller:

There is one scrollView that holds your content and has user interaction disabled, let's call it `contentScrollView`, and one invisible scrollView of the same size on top, `interactionScrollView`. In the delegate-controller for both, implement

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == interactionScrollView)
    {
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(yourProgrammaticallySetHorizontalOffset,interactionScrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [contentScrollView setContentOffset:offset];
    }
}
```

You can also link zooming in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this out today and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, since you probably don't really need horizontal *scrolling*, you just want to set the content's offset:

Put your contentView into a scrollView normally, but set the scrollView's contentSize as `CGPointMake(scrollView.size.width,content.size.height)`. This means the scrollView won't ever scroll horizontally.

Now, from your code, you can shift the content around horizontally: `content.frame = CGRectOffset(content.frame, yourPreferredOffset, 0)`.

I haven't tested this, but I thnk it's gonna work, and only needs one scrollView. You could also put that frame changing stuff into an animation to make it look like a scroll (which it is) instead of a sudden content change.